# bash: using grep to extract text from between strings

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file that reads like:

```
hello
We're so
excited to 
be learning computer
science today
    HOORAY
hooraaaay
```

I'm trying to extract:

```
We're so
excited to 
be learning computer
science today
    HOORAY
```

so everything between "We're" and "HOORAY" including the two words.

I'm using the command:

```
sed -n "/^We're so/,/^    HOORAY/p" file.txt
```

But it's not working (it doesn't stop after HOORAY). How would I fix this? Is there another way to approach the command?

Answer (score 3):

This simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed -n "/We're/,/HOORAY/p"   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `awk` too.

```
awk '/We\047re/,/HOORAY/'  Input_file
```